# ROS TurtleBot2 Unable to Communicate?

Tags: turtlebot2, turtlebot, catkin, camera, astra

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone.

I am currently doing research using the TurtleBot 2 and ROS Kinetic Kame. I'm trying to set up an Orrbec Astra camera with my TurtleBot. Instead of a netbook, we use Intel NUC nooks.

```
roslaunch astra_launch astra.launch
```

The above launch works, and several camera/ topics can be seen running; however, nothing is subscribing or publishing to any of the topics.

I pulled the driver from the ros_astra_camera repository (https://github.com/orbbec/ros_astra_camera), and used `catkin build` to build the astra_camera package.

This is what I get with `lsusb -v`

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 2bc5:0401
```

, so my hub recognizes and identifies the astra.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264613/ros-turtlebot2-unable-to-communicate?/) by [HaleyCurr](https://answers.ros.org/users/30885/haleycurr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tinkered a bit and restarted my NUC and the camera communicates now! :D

---

Originally posted by [HaleyCurr](https://answers.ros.org/users/30885/haleycurr/) with karma: 33 on 2017-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0